# c# visifire(charts)

Tags: asp.net, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0, visifire

I have developed one silverlight application on .net framework and used visifire for charting i.e. getting updated through MS SQL database.
The main thing is that when i am updating the database the data on chart are getting affected, but the look and feel of the chart is not happening smoothly during the value change.

I have used `<vc:DataSeries RenderAs="QuickLine"  DataSource="{Binding ItemsSource, ElementName=MyGrid}" >` for quickline presentation of the data on graph.

So what changes I have to make in my programm for smooth change in graph statistics after database updation.

Answer (score 0):

> "but the look and feel of the chart is
>   not happening smoothly during the
>   value change"

What is your expected output and what is the current output? Please explain more in detail. Which version of Visifire you are using? Exactly how you are updating the ItemsSource property? Can you provide C# code and XAML?

Comment: Hi, My expected output is the shifting of the charts view smoothly upon database updation. but upon data updation now it is happening in random way.

Comment: This is the answer of my first question. Can you please answer to my other queries also in detail so that I can help you to achieve your requirement?